# Mongodb: Finding items that are not present in the collection

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection called "inventory" that has 2 items

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0de48bce523d1df7546e9c"),
    "name" : "tshirt",
    "qty" : 5
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0de4acce523d1df7546ea8"),
    "name" : "pant",
    "qty" : 15
}
```

if I do a query like this

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $in: [ 5, 10 ] } } )
```

It will give the first object.

I want to construct a result like this in json form later to be returned through an API.

```
{
 "5" : "true"
 "10" : "false"
}
```

I have thought of the following options

- Creating a temporary collection of [10 ,15) and then using aggregrate function $lookup
- Looping through the list of items and doing a comparison check with [10,15] and constructing the desired output.

What other options can be done? The example is a small one but in the real application, the number of items is going to be in hundreds and thousands.

Comment: Or you could just simply return the logical result for each tested value as a boolean. This is what [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) in the aggregation framework already does.

Comment: $eq can only do a comparison between 2 distinct items and not check within a list of items.

Comment: `{ "$project": { "5": { "$eq": ["$qty", 5] }, "10": { "$eq": ["$qty",10] } }}` I try to leave a little room for application of grey matter up to the person trying to work it out. In brief you made no attempt whatsoever in your question, so instead of spoon feeding, I'm pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Apologies if there were some confusion.  [5,10] is just an example. I did mentioned that its going to be in hundreds and thousands in the real project.  $in is better than $eq in this case. The input is going to come as a variable so there is no way to know beforehand and write out the code in this fashion   
{ "$project": { "5": { "$eq": ["$qty", 5] }, "10": { "$eq": ["$qty",10] } }}

Answer (score 0):

The biggest challenge here is actually converting the `int` values in the input array into `string` keys. I think I've once seen code on Stack Overflow that would allow doing that but I also seem to remember it being terribly hacky.

The following code gets you pretty close to your goal, though.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "qties": {
            $addToSet: "$qty" // create an array of all unique "qty" values
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "results": {
            $map: {
                input: values, // go through all values that we want to test, e.g. [ 5, 10 ]
                in: { // and map them into the following new structure
                    $arrayToObject: // transform our generated array of key-value pairs into an object
                    [[
                        {
                            "v": "$$this", // this will be just each value we look at - one by one
                            "k": { $cond: [ { $in: [ "$$this", "$qties" ] }, "true", "false" ] } // and this will tell us if the looked at value exists in our documents (or rather: in our array of unique values that we've generated in the $group stage)
                        }
                    ]]

                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This will spit out the following structure:

```
{
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "true" : 5.0
        }, 
        {
            "false" : 10.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can write the following:

```
var values = [ 5, 10 ]

db.getCollection('test').aggregate({
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "qties": {
            $addToSet: "$qty" // create an array of all unique "qty" values
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "results": {
            $map: {
                input: values, // go through all values that we want to test, e.g. [ 5, 10 ]
                in: { // and map them into the following new structure
                    "value": "$$this", // this will be just the value we look at
                    "found": { $cond: [ { $in: [ "$$this", "$qties" ] }, "true", "false" ] } // and this will tell us if the looked at value exists in our documents (in the array of unique values rather)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$results" // flatten the results array
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$results" // move the contents of the "results" field all the way up
    }
})
```

...which will yield these two documents:

```
{
    "value" : 5.0,
    "found" : "true"
}
{
    "value" : 10.0,
    "found" : "false"
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close. Thanks